# In Oracle, how to delete a row with a specific value, only if it is a duplicate?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
Create Table testpo
( 
    poid Varchar2(10),
    ToDelete Varchar2(10)
);

Insert into testpo values (‘PO1’, ‘D’);
Insert into testpo values (‘PO1’, ‘N’);
Insert into testpo values (‘PO2’, ‘D’);
Insert into testpo values (‘PO3’, ‘D’);
```

I want to create a stored procedure to return the unique POIds but if there is D and N for same POid, I only need the row with IsDelete = N

Output needed :

```
PO1 N
PO2 D
PO3 D
```

Comment: Your title asks how to delete a row and the body of the question asks how to "return the unique poid`s" which one do you want to do? Delete or select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `SELECT` the unique `poid` prioritising `ToDelete` values of `N` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT poid,
       ToDelete
FROM   (
  SELECT poid,
         todelete,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY poid ORDER BY ToDelete DESC) AS rn
  FROM   testpo
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

If you want to `DELETE` the non-unique rows (again, prioritising retaining `ToDelete` values of `N`) then you can use:

```sql
DELETE FROM testpo
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY poid ORDER BY ToDelete DESC) AS rn
    FROM   testpo
  )
  WHERE  rn > 1
)
```

The output from the `SELECT` and the rows remaining after the `DELETE` are:

| POID | TODELETE |
| --- | --- |
| PO1 | N |
| PO2 | D |
| PO3 | D |

If you want it as a procedure then wrap it in a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement and return a `SYS_REFCURSOR` variable to contain the output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y1E9G2bg)

Answer (score 3):

This is an other way to return the unique POIds prioritising ToDelete with value N, using the aggregate function `MAX()`, in case where duplicates have values 'N' and 'D', it will return 'N', as 'N' is considered greater than 'D' :

```
SELECT poid, MAX(ToDelete) as ToDelete
FROM testpo
GROUP BY poid
```

Results :

```
POID    TODELETE
PO1     N
PO2     D
PO3     D
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DS0elAg7)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a rank and delete the required record using rowid

```
select poid, todelete, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY poid ORDER BY todelete) as row_number, rowid from testpo;
```

```
delete from testpo where rowid in
(select rowid from 
(select poid, todelete, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY poid ORDER BY todelete) as row_number, rowid from testpo)
where row_number = 2);
```

[image]

Result

[image]